# float table misalignment, table crosses the page width

Tags: tables, floats, tabularx

I am using the IEEEtran template. I am trying to build a table that is a single column as the text in the second column is wide. I used table* for float tables but the text in the second column is always misaligned and exceeds the page limits. I tried using tabularx also. After this, the text in the second column is within the page limits but there is no separation between the two columns of the table.

below is the code

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{dblfloatfix}


\begin{document}
\title{A Review}

begin{table*}[t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{Summary of the 6G features and applications.}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}

\toprule

6G Feature & Description\\
\hline
Tiny Cells & Works well with higher mmWave and THz frequencies. They are simple to install and configure, with the ability of restricting access to a specific set of users present at home or in an office environment.\\
\hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to try `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}`.

Comment: `begin{tabular}` you have not used the required argument ``{llllll}` or whatever you need, you must have got multiple errors from this?

Comment: @leandriis thank you so much. it worked.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes you are right. It has worked now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to actually providing a column specification for the `tabular` environment, you also need to change `begin{table*}[t]` to `\begin{table*}[t]`, i.e., supply a missing backslash character. And, since you're loading the `booktabs` package, I'd get rid of all stray `\hline` directives.

For the table at hand, the specification for the second column should allow automatic linebreaking. One way to do so is to replace `tabular` with `tabularx`, select `X` as the type for the second column, and set a suitable overall width of the `tabularx` environment. For the material at hand, I'd choose an overall width of between `0.8\textwidth` and `1\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{Summary of 6G features and applications.}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{@{} l X @{}}
\toprule
6G Feature & Description \\
\midrule
Tiny Cells & Works well with higher mmWave and THz frequencies. 
They are simple to install and configure, with the ability of 
restricting access to a specific set of users present at home 
or in an office environment. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```